# Using http post in android app

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpclient

I need to do simple http post in my app.

Found example and created `AsyncTask` class. The main code doing post is this:

`nameValuePairs` - is post elements

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL_STRING);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
String data = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
```

How ever i get this exception

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Forbidden
```

What does this means ? If this something that service return, then how to see full message ?

Also if there are other way to make http post, i could try it :)

Thank you guys for help.

Comment: have you added INTERNET permission into menifest file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception `org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException` Signals a non 2xx HTTP response as stated here : http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpResponseException.html.

You can use the simple httpPOST method as below :

```
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();    
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://Your URL/");      
        try {        
         // Add your data        
         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);        
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name1", "Value1"));        
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name2", "Value2"));     
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name3", "Value3"));    

          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));          
        // Execute HTTP Post Request        
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);             
         } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {       
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block    
         } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {         
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
          }
```